# How to return empty Vector as a result of Task?

Tags: scala, task, scala-cats, zio

I have created a simple project and one of the method is (it is `ZIO` Task

`type Task[+A] = ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]`):

```
def findSmth(..) : Task[Either[Exception, Vector[SomeData]]]
```

I would like to return an empty Vector in some cases.
I tried to do it this way:

```
ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ctx =>
   Future.successful(Right(Seq.empty[SomeData].toVector))
}
```

or

```
ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ctx =>
   Future.successful(Right(Vector.empty))
}
```

But it always return `None` instead of empty vector (empty list).
How should I refactor this code to return just an empty result (vector with no data inside), without exceptions or Nones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the `apply` method on the `Task` object,

```
Task(Right(Vector.empty))
```

Comment: It still return None instead of empty Vector

Comment: @allocer what do you mean with it returns `None`? There is no **Option** anywhere, maybe you should show more code? Also, why using `fromFuture`? Maybe you simplified your code too much. BTW, I am pretty sure that a `ZIO[Either]` is a bad practice. - Martijn, I believe there should be a `pure` like method in **ZIO**.

Comment: @allocer, at the risk of sounding contrarian, no, it doesn't. It returns a `Task[Either[Nothing, Vector[Nothing]]]`, and None is not a value of that type